# Callbacks not working properly

Tags: javascript, callback, jquery-callback

I'm at a loss.  In this code, #options should wind up fading in, but it doesn't.  The CSS attributes are set, though.

```
$("#content > p").animate({ opacity: '0' }, function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $("#options").css("opacity", "0").show(0, function() {
        $("#options").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: how about you do one line of code: `$("#options").fadeIn();` that should be enough

Comment: but i need it to also set display: block, hence the show function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `opacity` is still being set as `0`.

You can change the `fadeIn()` to...

```
$("#options").animate({ opacity: 1}, 500);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdzGa/).

Comment: @John - If this answers your question, make sure and click the outlined checkmark next to the question. :) (Not that @alex needs the points, mind you... :P)

Comment: @Jared Could always do with another 15 :P

Comment: @alex - I'd give it to you if I could. Although @patrick dw also has a compelling answer...

Comment: @Jared He has a better answer so I +1'd it :)

Comment: oh alex... you're far too kind. :o) Here's a + backatcha.

Comment: I was going to hit the check button, but there is a limit on the amount of time you must wait before accepting an answer as correct.  Please forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it should work, but apparently you'd need to use the [`fadeTo()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method instead of the [`fadeIn()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method.

```
$('img').css("opacity", 0).show(0,function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(400, 1);
});
```

---

Although the `show(0,func..` seems kinda pointless here, when you could just do:

```
$('img').css("opacity", 0).show().fadeTo(400, 1);
```

...unless the `0` you're giving for the `.show()` duration is actually a variable that may reference a larger number.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a lot - remember setting opacity to 0 will replicate the `visibility:hidden` CSS attribute, whereas `fadeOut()` will replicate the `display:none` CSS attribute. The one critical difference between these two is that the latter will remove the element from rendered DOM so it will not take up space on the screen and the surrounding nodes won't even know it's there. The former will create a big empty box where the element **still is** but you just can't see it. Assuming you want to use the latter which is the most common, this should work:

```
$('#content > p').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#options').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: You don't understand.  It has display: none; by default, so I need the show function to change it to block.

Comment: `fadeIn()` will set it to `display:block` automatically